# Error message in python 3 object has no attribute 'min_data'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I wondered if anyone could interpret what this error message means for me? I am trying to run lead 210 data using PyPlum https://github.com/maquinolopez/PyPlum/blob/PyPlum/README.md

I have downloaded all of the requirements using either `conda install -c conda-forge` or `sudo easy_install` and I am using miniconda. There definitely is data in the folder so I am not sure what it is telling me?

Thanks

My code is as follows:

```
conda activate my-py

   cd pytwalk-1.5

   sudo python3 setup.py install

   cd /Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum

   python3
```

---

```
   import PyPlum as Plum

   BB = Plum.Plum("BB")

   BB.runPlum()
```

That should run the model however I am getting the error:

```
BB = Plum.Plum("BB")>>> BB = Plum.Plum("BB")
There is no 210Pb data
There is no 14C data or calendar dates
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum/PyPlum.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.def_breaks()
  File "/Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum/PyPlum.py", line 117, in def_breaks
    self.breaks         =   array(arange(min(self.min_data,self.min_date),max(self.max_data,self.max_date)+2*self.by,self.by))
AttributeError: 'Plum' object has no attribute 'min_data'
>>> BB = Plum.Plum("BB")
There is no 210Pb data
There is no 14C data or calendar dates
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum/PyPlum.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.def_breaks()
  File "/Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum/PyPlum.py", line 117, in def_breaks
    self.breaks         =   array(arange(min(self.min_data,self.min_date),max(self.max_data,self.max_date)+2*self.by,self.by))
AttributeError: 'Plum' object has no attribute 'min_data'
```

[image: Image of csv]

Answer (score 0):

I checked [this source file](https://github.com/maquinolopez/PyPlum/blob/PyPlum/PyPlum.py) and it seems that the `Plum` object had not loaded some `14C` data to `self.min_data` in the `load_data` method.

Make sure that you have a `~/Documents/PyPlum/BB/BB-C.csv` file containing the `14C` data. (I have no idea what that is..)

Answer (score 0):

[Pyplum docs](https://github.com/maquinolopez/PyPlum): To load the package use:

```
import PyPlum
```

Edit the import line on your code and try.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing both if conditions: 157 & 199 in [this file.](https://github.com/maquinolopez/PyPlum/blob/PyPlum/PyPlum.py)
Hence the message:

1. There is no 210Pb data
2. There is no 14C data or calendar dates

Can you print the file name and see if those file exist for you? (~/Documents/PyPlum/BB/BB.csv & ~/Documents/PyPlum/BB/BB-C.csv)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the problem was for some reason the files had to be in the Documents folder not my root folder sophiewilliams

Thanks everyone

Comment: this is detailed in the docs https://github.com/maquinolopez/PyPlum#retting-folders

Comment: `Plum(Core='BB',dirt="/Users/sophiewilliams/PyPlum")` should have worked, if you had files in your root folder